# introduce a restrictive clause without using that

Tags: relative-clauses

That/which/who are commonly used to introduce a restrictive clause. But some sentences sound fine even without it.

Example:

> John received medicines under development in the research lab.

OR

> John received medicines that were under development in the research
>   lab.

Is there a grammar issue with the first sentence for formal piece? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence works just as well with the relative clause as without it.

In the first sentence, the prepositional phrase "*under development*" modifies the direct object "*medicines*" directly rather than through the relative clause you added to the second sentence.

Comment: However, using the relative clause reduces the chance of misconstruing it to mean that John received medicines "in the research lab".

Comment: I see your point. Can this be misconstrued? "John's treatment included medicines under development in the research lab."

Comment: It *could* be misconstrued, but if you wanted to indicate that ***he received them in the lab*** you would likely rewrite the sentence to make **that** clear. The intuitive interpretation of a reader is that modifiers appear **immediately** before or after the words they modify.

Comment: @JoeBlack: I'm with you. The sentence "John's treatment included medicines . . ." cannot be misconstrued, in my opinion, having as it does its subject, "treatment"; its verb, "included"; its object, "medicines"; and its modifiers, both "John's" and "under development in the research lab." As such it's a well constructed, perfectly understandable sentence. Don

Comment: Careful Joe ! There are a lot of idiots out there who COULD misconstrue, "I sat in my chair." LOL! Communication is a negotiation.